# Valums uploader and DB save on multiple files

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using valums uploader with an ashx file example that I found & tweeked, and want to save data from each file to the db when I upload, stepping through the code , there doesn't seem any way to differentiate which file is uploaded in which order , watching certain variable ,  the code jumps all over the place. It works fine for single files but more than 1 is an issue. Also, context.Request.Files.Count is always 0

```
            byte[] buffer = new byte[request.ContentLength];

            fileName = request.RawUrl.Split('=')[1];
            fmt = Path.GetExtension(fileName);

            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(request.InputStream)) 
            br.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            File.WriteAllBytes(StorageRoot + request["qqfile"], buffer);

            success = false;
            context.Response.Write("{success:true}");
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I've used valums uploader without problem. Different browsers upload files in different ways. IE will use an file upload html control, whilst Firefox & Chrome can do it Ajax style. I wrote my own upload handler, but the first thing you need to do is figure which method was used.

I do this like this:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["qqfile"] != null)
    file = new UploadedFileXhr();
else if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count > 0)
    file = new UploadedFileForm();
else
    return new UploadResult("Request was not valid.");
```

An XHR upload means you read from the input buffer like so:

```
int read = HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

while (read == buffer.Length)
{
    ms.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    read = HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}

ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
```

A file upload is simpler like so:

```
UploadResult result = new UploadResult(true);
result.Stream = _File.InputStream;
result.Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(_File.FileName);
```

Even if you add multiple files in the client, each file is uploaded individually.

Comment: Very nice, may come in handy when I start browser testing, for now I set the maxConnections to 1 and that did the trick nicely